# Ĉu estas ĝusta frazo "Mi permesas ke vi faru tion"?

Tags: verbs, subordinate-clauses

Mi multe legas kaj aŭdas ĉi tiajn frazojn:

> Mi permesas ke vi faru tion.

Ĉu ĉi tio estas ĝusta uzo de la imperativo? Se jes, kial oni rajtas uzi ĝin ĉi tie? Mi trovis la regulon ke oni uzu la imperativon por ordonoj, deziroj kaj petoj. Sed permeso estas neniu el ili.

Mi ankaŭ povus imagi la formojn "faras", "faros" kaj "farus".

Kompreneble ĉiam eblas eviti la subfrazon kaj uzi infinitivon:

> Mi permesas al vi fari tion.

Sed ĉar multaj Esperantistoj uzas subfrazon en tiu kazo, mi volis demandi kiu estas la ĝusta formo de la verbo en tiu kazo (se ekzistas) kaj kial.

Answer (score 3):

[PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/vola.html) uzas la terminojn vola modo, u-modo kaj u-formo pri verboj kun la u-finaĵo. La baza signifo de u-moda verbo estas laŭ PMEG:

> U-formo montras, ke la ago aŭ stato ne estas reala, sed dezirata, volata, ordonata aŭ celata. U-formo ne montras la tempon de la ago, sed la ago ordinare troviĝas en la estonteco.

Do

- *laboru* = la ago "labori" estas dezirata, petata, ordonata aŭ celata

Kiam temas pri ke-frazoj, PMEG konstatas, ke

> U-modo estas uzata en ke-frazoj, se la ĉeffrazo iel montras volon, celon, opinion k.s.

- *Mi volas, ke vi **laboru**.* La laborado estas volata.

Notu la kondiĉon "se la ĉeffrazo…" Alivorte ne ĉiuj ke-frazoj havu sian ĉefverbon en la u-modo. Fakte PMEG havas apartan [ĉapitron pri verboformoj en ke-frazoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/ke/verboformoj.html) kun testo, ĉu eblas memstrarigi la ke-frazon (ekzemploj kun emfazoj de PMEG).

- *Mi diris, ke li **venos**. → "Li **venos**." Tion mi diris.*
- *Mi estas feliĉa, ke mi vin **akceptos**. → Mi vin **akceptos**. Mi estas feliĉa pro tio.*

Se eblas memstarigi la ke-frazon tiel, uzu la saman verboformon en la ke-frazo kiel en la memstarigita frazo.

La ĉefverbo en la ĉeffrazo difinas la sencon de la ke-frazo. Tiu kutime estas celo, opinio, eblo aŭ imaga ago. Jen sekvas resumo el tiu supre menciita ĉapitro pri verboformoj en ke-frazoj.

## celo

Se la ke-frazo montras celon, tiam oni ofte uzas la u-modon laŭ la baza signifo de u-modaj verboj.

- *Mi volas, ke vi tien **iru**.*

Kutime en tiaj okazoj la verbo en la ĉeffrazo estas *voli, deziri, ordoni, admoni, postuli, peti, proponi, konsili, bezoni* aŭ esprimo *esti necese* aŭ simila.

## opinio

En frazoj, kiuj montras opinion, oni uzu realan modon, se opinio estas pri reala afero, kaj u-modon pri nerealaĵo aŭ ĝenerala principo.

- *Estis ne dece, ke mi ridis.* La ridado fakte okazis, kaj tio estis nedeca.
- *Estas pli bone, ke ni tie ĉi manĝu kaj iru en la urbon vespere.* (principo)

Kelkfoje opinio estas nur ŝajna kaj fakte temas pri volo.

- *Ĉu vi konsentas, ke ni vojaĝu kune? ≈ Ĉu vi volas, ke ni vojaĝu kune.*

## eblo

Kelkfoje la ĉeffrazo estas konstato pri eblo de ago, kiun oni esprimas en la ke-frazo. Tiam oni uzu realan modon.

- *Estas eble, ke li alvenos morgaŭ.*

## imaga ago

Se ke-frazo montras ion imagan, la verbo estu en la imaga modo (us-finaĵo), se ion realan, en iu reala modo.

- *Mi estas certa, ke li **venus**, se li povus.* Li ne povas.
- *Mi estas certa, ke li **venos**, se li povos.* Eble li povos.

## la frazo "mi permesas, ke vi faru tion"

Kiun verboformon oni uzu en jena ke-frazo? Eblas memstrarigi la frazojn:

- "Mi permesas, ke vi faru tion" → "Vi faru tion. Mi permesas ĝin al vi ."

Ĉar tia memstrarigado eblas, oni uzu la saman verboformon en la ke-frazo kiel en la memstarigita frazo.

Comment: Dankon por la klarigoj kaj por la ideo de transformi la frazon. Eble alia transformo estus pli fidela al la originala frazo? "Mi ne ordonas ke vi ne faru tion." Ĝi havas la saman strukturon kaj relative precise la saman sencon, kaj la verbo "ordoni" indikas ke ni uzu la imperativon laŭ la klarigo de PMEG kiun vi menciis.

Answer (score 1):

Tute ĝusta uzo. La "imperativo" ne nur ordonas. Fakte *alreala modo* estas pli taŭga nomo (nu ja "modo" ne): ne iu realigita fakto, sed aspiro al ĝi.

Estas pluraj aliaj nuancoj kia:

```
Mi aprobas se vi volus fari tion.
```

Ĉi tie **-us** tamen ne estas adekvata. La sinonimo de ĉi tiu signifo de *permesi* estas *allasi*. Kaj tiam klare temas pri alreala modo.

```
Mi allasas ke vi faru tion.
```

Comment: Dankon! Mi komprenas kion vi klarigas pri la "alreala modo". Ĉu tio kongruas kun la fundamento (mi pensas ke tie oni parolas pri "imperativo"? Kie oni definis tiun larĝan version de la imperativo?

Comment: Kaj alia demando: Se la "alrealan modon" oni uzas por esprimi aspiro al iu, kial mi ne povas diri "Mi faru tion" por esprimi "Mi volas/celas fari tion."? Nur ĉar ĝi konfliktus kun la alia ebla senco "Mi devas fari tion"?

Comment: "Mi faru tion" por voli estas miaopinie ĝusta. Kiel "Lasu min fari tion". Naciaj lingvoj same havas (angle) got to/have to, (germane) müssen/sollen

Answer (score 1):

Tio ĝustas. Tamen estas alia eblo.

Anstataŭ:

```
permesi ke iu faru ion
```

la pli malpeza:

```
permesi al iu fari ion
```

Jen kelkaj ekzemploj Zamenhofaj:

```
Sed permesu, Via reĝida moŝto, sciigi vin,
permesu al mi kisi vian manon
malpermesis al la pastroj fumi tabakon
```

Comment: Jes, dankon. Kiel mi jam diris en la demando, mi ankaŭ preferas la infinitivan version.

Comment: Jes, mi nun vidas. Mi ne scias ĉu mia respondo do aldonas ion ... Eble mi viŝu.